# cast StringArray to String[] inside SOAP client

Tags: java, google-app-engine, soap-client, arrays

i have a service of SOAP webservice that return `ArrayList<String[]>`. When i call it from client, eclipse says me that service don't return `ArrayList<String[]>` but `List<StringArray>`.

`StringArray` don't seems to be a java data type, and i would know how i can convert it to `String[]` and extract data from it.

this is client imported file contains method for retrieve data:

```
@WebService(name = "Functions", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface Functions {


/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     returns java.util.List<com.example.StringArray>
 */
@WebMethod
@WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "getData", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/", className = "com.example.GetData")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "getDataResponse", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/", className = "com.example.GetDataResponse")
@Action(input = "http://example.com/Functions/getDataRequest", output = "http://example.com/Functions/getDataResponse")
public List<String[]> getData();
```

this is how this function is declared on server:

```
@WebMethod
public ArrayList<String[]> getData() {
    // invoked by android app
    dataStore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    ArrayList<Entity> list = (ArrayList<Entity>) dataStore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(100));

    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        ArrayList<String[]> res=new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String[] to_add;
        // convert entity into strings
        for (Entity current : list) {
            to_add=new String[3];
            to_add[0]=String.valueOf(current.getProperty(TEMP_ROW));
            to_add[1]=String.valueOf(current.getProperty(HUM_ROW));
            to_add[2]=String.valueOf(current.getProperty(DATE_ROW));

            res.add(to_add);
        }
        return res;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I think you should provide some code.

Comment: added code from my project

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29) method from the [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29)

```
List<String> myList = myClient.getData();
String[] myArray = myList.toArray();
```

Comment: Maybe i'm explane wrong myself. The service declared on server retur a ArrayList<String[]>, not a ArrayList<String>. i can't call myClient.getData on a List<String[]> variable, because eclipse told me that getData return List<StringArray>

Comment: Hmm, ok missed that detail. However the implementation on the server doesn't matter. It is a web service, the data is send as a soap XML/request. Everything that counts is what your client is doing. Transfering a list of list doesn't sound ideal. Why don't you send a specific type over?

Comment: because that method retrieve a list of data from a datastore, and each String[] contains all property of single retrieved Entity.